# I can´t find my .pem private key in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-key, pem

So, I created a AWS EC2 instance. I prompts you for a private key during the creation and so I added it.

It should be called `jose_key.pem`

Now the problem is that I need to use it to create an SSH connection through Ansible and I can´t find where it is located.

If I do `cd ~/.ssh` on the `ec2-user` I can just see a file called `authorized_keys` but I can`t find the `jose_key.pem` file.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You should have downloaded your private key, when you've created. This is the only time you can do so. Afterwards it is your responsibility to store it somewhere securely. It seems that you can SSH to the EC2 instance. This means that you have the key locally. The `authorized keys` file list the public keys of the private keys that are allowed to connect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I do ```cat authorized_keys``` I can see my private key in there. So you are saying that there is no way to check the content of that private key right? I would need to create a new one and with it create a new instance? Thanks!

Comment: You don't see your private key. You see the public key corresponding to your private key. Since you can somehow ssh into there, create another private-public key pair, add the public key in authorized_keys and keep the new private key somewhere safely.

Comment: It sounds like you're able to connect to the instance via SSH (otherwise you wouldn't be able to look at the `authorized_keys` file). If yes, then you should find the PEM file in your SSH home directory. On Linux that's `$HOME/.ssh`; on Windows, somewhere in `My Documents`. Or, easier, you're probably specifying the path to that file when you make your SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve the key when you create it. You have to create a new key, then add it to the authorized keys in your EC2 instance to be able to connect to it via SSH.

1. Create a new key pair here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#KeyPairs
2. Extract the public key:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/describe-keys.html#retrieving-the-public-key (or if you already have PuTTY installed, you can also use PuTTYgen)
3. Log in to your instance using EC2 Istance Connect (which I assume you already used, as you could "`cd ~/.ssh` on the `ec2-user`")
4. Append the content of the public key you extracted to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
5. Now you can SSH into the EC2 instance using the the new private key.